# Getting multiple values from select statement into a variable of a procedure

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to craete a procedure where the input to the procedure will be a string like 'a,b,c,d' and output will be the values from a table which match the comma separated value from in IN sting.

For that --

```
create table test (nm varchar2(10));

insert into test values ('a');
insert into test values ('b');
insert into test values ('c');
insert into test values ('d');

select * from test;

NM
------
a
b
c
d
```

Now i am trying to make a procedure where the IN parameter will be the values of NM column of TEST table in a comma separated string like 'a,b,c,d,x,w' there could be false values also.

So the procedure will return only the values which are matching with NM column of the TEST table for this i have created This procedure ---

```
create or replace procedure p_test (p_nm IN varchar2 /*, p_out OUT  sys_refcursor*/)

is
  l_len number;
  l_val varchar2(10);
  l_val1 varchar2(10);

begin
  l_len := length(p_nm);

 -- dbms_output.put_line(l_len);

  begin

  for i in 1..l_len

  loop

  select  REGEXP_SUBSTR (p_nm, '([^,]*)(,|$)',1, i , NULL, 1) into l_val  from dual;

 --  dbms_output.put_line(l_val);

 --  open p_out for

   select * into l_val1 from test where nm = l_val;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_val1);

  exit when l_len is null;

  end loop;

  exception

    when no_data_found then

    null;

   end;

  exception

  when others then

    dbms_output.put_line('Error reason :'||sqlerrm||' error code :'||sqlcode);

 end;

 EXECUTE p_test('a,,b,c,d,q,w');



 OUTPUT --

 a
 b
 c
 d
```

This procedure is giving me output as i required but i need to get that result into a variable which should be OUT parameter of this procedure as it will be called by the JAVA of our application.

As i have already tried to use the refcursor (please see the commented part) but it is giving me no output while a call it.

Its a call to this procedure when i use the refcursor (by removing comments ).

```
 declare
  l_out sys_refcursor;
  l_val varchar2(20);
  l_str varchar2(20) := 'a,b,c,d';
begin
   p_test (l_str, l_out);
   loop
   fetch l_out into l_val;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_val);
    dbms_output.put_line('a');
  exit when l_out%notfound;

  end loop;
```

end;

So here i got stuck with that how to get the multiple output or am i missing something here and if there is a better approach to this requirement as i have come with this so i am sharing it here.

I am using ---

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Create collection in oracle. `create type list_of_varchar is table of varchar2(20);`
2) Use bulk collect into.

```
declare 
 cursor c_obj is select object_name from user_objects where length(object_name) < 20;
 arrays list_of_varchar;
begin 
  open c_obj;
    fetch c_obj bulk collect into arrays;
  close c_obj;  
  dbms_output.put_line('Fetched '||arrays.count);
end;
```

3*) And the same code execute in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
    Connection con = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection(); //my oracle connection

    String str = "declare " +
            " cursor c_obj is select object_name from user_objects where length(object_name) < 20;" +
            " arrays list_of_varchar;" +
            "begin " +
            "  open c_obj;" +
            "    fetch c_obj bulk collect into arrays;" +
            "  close c_obj;  " +
            "  dbms_output.put_line('Fetched '||arrays.count);"+
                             " ? := arrays;" +
            "end;";
   CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(str);
   cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "LIST_OF_VARCHAR");
   cs.execute();
   String[] strings = (String[])cs.getArray(1).getArray();
   for(String tmp : strings) {
       System.err.println(tmp);
   }
   cs.close();
   con.close();        
}
```